# KeyNotFound exception in dictionary immediately after add

Tags: .net, vb.net

We have a base class that most of our business objects inherit from.  The first time any child class is accessed, we run call a method to cache the various reflection data for future use.  Entries added to these collections are never removed.  When I get the error (at the With line), I can see that the type was correctly added into the _AllProperties dictionary (Count = 22) but not in the _ImplementedIParent dictionary (Count = 21).

The error is very intermittent.  I have been chasing it a few days and don't see any reason it should be happening.  I run VS2019 with all CLRE checked, and don't get any errors on the add, but it is not there on the following line.

Here is the pertinent code from the base class.

```
Public Class BaseClass
    Private Shared ReadOnly _AllProperties As Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of Type, List(Of PropertyInfo)) = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of Type, List(Of PropertyInfo))
    Private Shared ReadOnly _ImplementedIParent As Dictionary(Of Type, Dictionary(Of Type, BaseObjectParentDetail)) = New Dictionary(Of Type, Dictionary(Of Type, BaseObjectParentDetail))

    Protected Shared Sub BuildPropertyList(CurrentType As Type)
        Try
            SyncLock CurrentType
                If _AllProperties.ContainsKey(CurrentType) Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                _AllProperties.TryAdd(CurrentType, New List(Of PropertyInfo))
                _ImplementedIParent.Add(CurrentType, New Dictionary(Of Type, BaseObjectParentDetail))
                With _ImplementedIParent(CurrentType) '<-- Throws KeyNotFound exception here
                    'do stuff
                End With
            End SyncLock
        Catch ex As Exception
            'do error stuff
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The method is accessed via the shared constructor in a base class

```
Public Class Schedule
    Inherits BaseClass
    Shared Sub New()
        BuildPropertyList(GetType(Schedule))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `If _AllProperties.TryAdd(CurrentType, New List(Of PropertyInfo)) Then  (...)` then `With _ImplementedIParent  Dim outdict As Dictionary(Of Type, BaseObjectParentDetail) = Nothing If .TryGetValue(CurrentType, outdict) Then 'do stuff end if end with end if`

Comment: Why must you add the object then access it from the dictionary immediately? Just create a variable and do stuff then add it?

Comment: `If _AllProperties.TryAdd() ...` counts. Don't dismiss it.

Comment: Btw, you can try not to `SyncLock CurrentType`: use a Field of type `Object` instead. What matters is that concurrent threads cannot acquire a lock on the same object, so they need to wait in line to access the Dictionaries.